# kendoChart - Refresh only bars not whole graph

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I implemented kendo chart of Telerik and below is my code after applying updated values.

I would like to smoothly update only bar - like below LINK:

```
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Dynamic-Animated-jQuery-Bar-Charts-Plugin-LiveGraph/demo/
```

My existing code to refresh graph is:

```
var chart = $("#divBarChart").data("kendoChart");
chart.options.series[0].data = globalSeriesValue
chart.refresh();
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Kendo - the Chart API exposes setDataSource() method. So when you say you want to refresh just the bars its actually nothing but providing a new data source to the chart. This way the chart is not redrawn rather just the points on the chart are repainted.

here is the documentation link:http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#methods-setDataSource

I have created a demo for you here: http://dojo.telerik.com/@kashyapa/Ekara

Comment: Thanks, I did it using refresh() function.